# If $A$ is a set with $m$ elements and $C \subset A$ is a set with $1$ element, then $A-C$ is a set with $m-1$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a set with $m$ elements and $C \subset A$ is a set with $1$ element, then $A-C$ is a set with $m-1$ elements

Let $f:\mathbb{N_m} \to A$ and $g:\mathbb{N_1} \to C$. $f,g$ are both bijections I need to find a bijective map form $N_{m-1} \to (A-C)$. Now intuitively i can see that in our new map we can define as same way as in $f$. But how to remove $1$ element from $f$ map and leave others as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** define $\Bbb N_{m-1}\to (A-C)$ as (roughly) the restriction of $f$ to a subset of $\Bbb N_m$ you have to choose.

**Edit:** let $c$ the element of $C$ and $\gamma:=f^{-1}(c)$. Then we can restrict $f$ to $\Bbb N_m - \{\gamma\}$: this restriction $f'$ gives a bijection (check it!) $\Bbb N_m - \{\gamma\}\to (A-C)$. If you compose $f'$ with a bijection $\Bbb N_{m-1}\to \Bbb N_m - \{\gamma\}$, you obtain a bijection $\Bbb N_{m-1}\to (A-C)$.

Comment: what do you mean by restriction of f

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, see my edit above.

Comment: So you mean removing preimage of element of C from original f. But why to compose (as in your last line)?

Comment: The composition is useful to obtain a function whose domain is exactly $\Bbb N_{m-1}$, contrary to $f'$.

Comment: Restriction means to remove element and its preimage. so $ f' $  will also be bijection.. Am i right? Thanks

Comment: Since we removed an element and its preimage, $f'$ is a bijection: that's right. But restriction doesn't mean what you say. It only means replacing the domain of the function by one of its subsets (and no change on the codomain).

Comment: But if we restrict domain and donot change in codomain then will not bijectivity effects ? I mean some elements will be  left out which donot have pre image

Comment: Yes, that's why I restricted *and* I changed the codomain: these are 2 different operations I made at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for help. i want to upvote answer but i need 15 points for that. I f you may upvote my question then i can upvote answer

Comment: You're welcome!